# Custom segued view with lots of elements slow

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

When I trigger my CatalogController like so on an iPad 3 (in the Simulator it takes under a second, but that's not relevant):

```
- (IBAction)goToCatalog:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"goToCatalogPre");
    [self presentViewController:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CatalogController"] animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"goToCatalogPost");
}
```

I get this result:

```
2016-03-23 11:27:07.245 Fashion App[592:78778] goToCatalogPre
2016-03-23 11:27:13.571 Fashion App[592:78778] goToCatalogPost
```

So that's a rough 6.25 seconds. I tested the viewDidLoad from start to end and literally takes a few nanoseconds. Nothing else triggers besides that call.

I have these delegates attached to my ViewController:

```
@interface CatalogController : CoreController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

`CoreController` only does one variable tracking so there's not slowness there.

Anyone have any experience what might cause this anomaly? Honestly I could deconstruct all the elements to trace it back but I was wondering if anyone might have encountered this before and what might cause it or where other I can trace it than in the `viewDidLoad` call.

Here are the elements in my storyboard on this view:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to log stg into the awakeFromNib method of UIViewController ? I personally implemented interfaces with really a lot of UI elements and I've never had delay problems like the one described. If you don't perform any extra long operation on the main tread, You can try to remove from parent view, blocks of UI elements (programmatically), and then check if the delay really change, Maybe is due a specific UI element

Comment: awakeFromNib on the `CatalogController ` responds within 11ms after logging `goToCatalogPre`. I guess it really comes down to breaking down this down to the element after all yes. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: You could try present the new VC with almost all subviews hidden (literally setHidden:YES, or directly from storyboard ), and then present them with a sort of fade-in effect ( setAlpha:0;setHidden:NO;animation.. ) presenting them in a specific fade-in order, so you could change the issue in a UI effect ;) Of course, if this make all smoother and will kill down the delay

Comment: I tried with just setting everything to hidden as a test and it didn't change a fraction of the loading time. It almost looks like the delegates are doing something odd. Edit: Even removing the delegates doesn't change a thing :(. So awkward.. There are no background processes running either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Time Profiler and it literally happens under the hood. At some point it hits a UIButton (69% of the total run time), then deeper down the line it TBaseFont:CopyLocalizedName(__CFString const*) and from there it splits into 33% and 22% (and some remainder) into some localized cache and TBaseFont::CopyNativeFont() const. Guess I'll have to go about all buttons and see which one might cause this.

After some tracing I found (through this answer: [Xib taking long time (>1s) to load. UIFont cache seems to blame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735005/xib-taking-long-time-1s-to-load-uifont-cache-seems-to-blame)) that it was a old missing font fault. It tries to load an old variation of Lucida Grande and it somehow seems to stall the cache making it freak out. Correcting the font to become System again fixed it. The load time instantly is just a few milliseconds.